Can I Safely Remove zone.js Dependency in Angular 18 with Experimental Zoneless Change Detection?
Question: Can I Safely Remove zone.js Dependency in Angular 18 with Experimental Zoneless Change Detection?
I'm using the latest Angular version (18.1.0) and have activated the experimental zoneless change detection with the following configuration:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideExperimentalZonelessChangeDetection(),
    // Other providers...
  ]
};

I have also removed zone.js from the polyfills array inside angular.json.
My question is: Is it safe to completely remove the zone.js dependency from my project? Neither the official documentation nor other resources provide clear guidance on whether it's safe to remove this dependency entirely.
Additional Information:

I haven't encountered any issues so far, but I want to ensure that this approach won't cause problems in the future.
Are there any known caveats or potential pitfalls with removing zone.js when using the experimental zoneless change detection?


if you are using zoneless change detection - zonejs isn't used. I.e. adding provideExperimental... is not safe. just removing a dependency is safe. in js world only explicitly included into bundle dependencies are working on runtime. just adding something to node_modules( like adding to classpath) doesn't do anything

Enabling zoneless is exactly this : build and run angular without the zone.js dependency.
The NgZone implementation will not rely on zone.js but on a dummy implementation called NoopNgZone.
